# Firefox and Chrome long delay before launching webdriver (Protractor/Jasmine/Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

As of lately, when I launch my protractor E2E tests in Firefox and Chrome it seems to take a good 20-30 seconds before loading the initial URL through the webdriver.  On test launch, the browser opens immediately but then sits on a blank page for the brief time delay before processing again.

I'm just curious to know if there's a capability or something that may need edited due to being on current versions.

I'm running chromedriver 2.26, latest geckodriver, latest webdriver-manager (i believe it's 11 something), and latest chrome/firefox browser version.  Protractor is on 5.0.0.  Everything works properly in IE.

My config for the browsers look like:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'shardTestFiles': 'true',
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'maxInstances': '1',
        //'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': 'true',
        //'enablePersistentHover': 'true',
        //"ie.ensureCleanSession": 'true',
        //"ie.forceCreateProcessApi": 'true',
        'ignoreZoomSetting': 'true',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        //'handlesAlerts': 'true',
        //'enableElementCacheCleanup': 'true',
        //'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': '["accept", "dismiss", "ignore"]',
        //'applicationCacheEnabled': 'true',
        //directConnect: true,

        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--start-maximized', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-web-security', '--enable-screenshots'],
        },

        //for firefox
        //'marionette': 'true',
        //'firefoxOptions': {
            //'args': ['start-maximized']
        //},
     }],
```

Comment: Where is `'--enable-screenshots'` coming from? I couldn't find it in the docs http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Honestly no idea, I think someone on here told me to try it since `browser.takeScreenshot()` doesnt work in chrome for me.  It didn't work though and I just haven't taken it out.  But that's not the cause of the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Can you remove that non-existing option and try to run the tests in https://github.com/zalando/zalenium ?